# swupdate explicit mark of successful update

Tags: embedded, updates, boot, flashing

Use case:

- A/B symmetrical partitions
- flashing a new image was successful
- system rebooted to the newly flashed partition
- almost everything is running fine except few components -> not a successful update, it should boot the old partition on the next reboot

Rauc has a mechanism for explicitly marking the success with `rauc status mark-good`.

I can't find anything similar in the swupdate documentation. Is it there or the swupdate considers just a successful flashing as a fully successful update?

Answer (score 1):

see progree-interface in the documentation to forward the result of the update. Switching A/B via bootloader is set as last step in SWUpdate - it is never done if an update is unsuccessful